# user is already taken?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password_input = $_POST["password"];
$password = md5($password_input);
$email_input = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$email = md5($email_input);

if (!($stmt  = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`password`,`email_address`) VALUES (?,?,?)")) || !is_object($stmt)) {
    die( "Error preparing: (" .$con->errno . ") " . $con->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
echo "User has been Created! Feel free to login - <a href='login.php'><span class='button color_blue'>Login</span></a>";
```

Within the SQL database an email/username can only be used once (UNIQUE) and I wondered if there was a way to change the echo to only appear if the data was successfully added and then a different message for if it wasn't successful.

Thanks - I'm still a rookie!

**EDIT:** so after using some code from the answer i am now at:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password_input = $_POST["password"];
$password = md5($password_input);
$email_input = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$email = md5($email_input);

if (!($stmt  = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`password`,`email_address`) VALUES (?,?,?)")) || !is_object($stmt)) {die( "Error preparing: (" .$con->errno . ") " . $con->error);}
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
if ($con->affected_rows == 1) {echo "User has been Created! Feel free to login - <a href='login.php'><span class='button color_blue'>Login</span></a>";}
var_dump($con->affected_rows);
```

successful and unsuccessful INSERTS for some reason all have -1 as their "affected rows" output

Comment: check about affected rows method.

Comment: Look on Security.SE for best-practices regarding passwords, but the short note is that MD5 is a joke.  Assuming that you don't want to allow too-similar usernames/emails, you need to do [Unicode canonicalization before attempting to check for existence](http://labs.spotify.com/2013/06/18/creative-usernames/).  Why are you hashing emails - can people not recover their accounts?  Heck, how are you ever planning on notifying them for anything (such as a password breach)?

Comment: @clockwork-muse i was hashing emails while i was testing incase i needed to give out the link to people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute() method returns true if successful.

Replace:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

with:

```
if($stmt->execute()) { 
    echo "user created!";
} else {
    echo "error: " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: I would not show actual mysql error to the user if they try to insert username that already exists

Comment: Agreed, certainly not in production but thought it might help during development/testing :)

Answer (score 0):

To check for successful UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE query, you would need to check if returned affected rows are more than zero.

http://php.net/mysqli_affected_rows

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE,
>   REPLACE or DELETE query.

In your case:

```
if ($con->affected_rows == 1) {
    echo "User has been Created! Feel free to login - <a href='login.php'><span class='button color_blue'>Login</span></a>";
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but it doesn't work :/ Maybe i should replace "== 1" with ">= 0" just to make sure it isn't the code?

Comment: just `>` because `>=0` will display `created user` even if `0` rows are affected. But I think it was because I had written `$conn` and your object was `$con`. Just make sure which is your mysqli object and user affected_rows thourgh it

Comment: Good Point, I'll double check

Comment: Hi, so I've checked and tested: "== 1" doesn't give a message even though it was successful. Any idea why? `if ($con->affected_rows == 1) {echo "User has been Created! Feel free to login - <a href='login.php'><span class='button color_blue'>Login</span></a>";}`

Comment: dump the affected rows to see what it does return

Comment: ^^' meaning? Sorry I'm a rookie :s

Comment: `var_dump($con->affected_rows)`

Comment: unsuccessful and successful both come back as -1 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to check if the query was successful or not:

change the end of your code by this:

```
$success = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
if ($success)
  echo "User has been Created! Feel free to login - <a href='login.php'><span class='button color_blue'>Login</span></a>";
else
  echo "Impossible to create that user: ".$stmt->error;
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide many different messages I work with flags. Simply say: if the username equals an existing db name, userExistMsg = 1. 
To check if the User Exists, simply use a SELECT query in sql and ask for any entrys on the given user. This query should result in none obkects if the username is free.

Btw. You seem to use simple md5 for pw encoding. That's not verry secure. Better use something like salted passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is a sample answer change this according to your code..

```
     $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password_input = $_POST["password"];
        $password = md5($password_input);
        $email_input = $_POST["emailaddress"];
        $email = md5($email_input);

        $con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USER","PASSWORD","your_db");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users WHERE username = $username ");

      $datacount2 = mysql_num_rows($result );  
        if($datacount2 < 1)
        {
        if (!($stmt  = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`password`,`email_address`) VALUES (?,?,?)")) || !is_object($stmt)) {
            die( "Error preparing: (" .$con->errno . ") " . $con->error);
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

    if($stmt)
     {
        echo "User has been Created! Feel free to login - <a href='login.php'><span class='button color_blue'>Login</span></a>";
      }
      else
     {
     echo "Insert Failed";
     }
        }

        else
        {
        echo "User already exists..";
        }
```

Comment: Almost works, for some reason it still says "user already exists" when an INSERT is successful :s

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.. I've edit the code if($result > 0) should be **if($result < 1)** or **if($result == 0)**

Comment: This time the error is, that no matter if the **INSERT is successful or not - it still gives the "user created" message** ^^'

Comment: Edit the code... 
**mysqli_prepare()** returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Comment: Still **the same issue** ^^' Feel free to keep trying, I'm gonna do some googling see if anyone has had this strange issue

Comment: Still after having if conditions you getting that message?? Do you check wether you insert your data correctly to the database or not..

Comment: Check it out if you want: http://2v2.lolnode.com/register.php?type=1 try registering the same account twice.

Comment: Did you check the database and tables whether they contains the data you 've entered or not. If you get this message when you correctly enter data, it's ok.. 
I checked your link.. nice work !! :)

Comment: Yeah everything is working, got your register: aaa , did you try registering aaa again?

Comment: Yeah.. I tried it again..
Have you checked for existing users. Before inserting with a SELECT query..

Comment: I've changed the code above
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users WHERE username = $username ");
$dataCount=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($dataCount< 1)
        {

try that one

Comment: I've changed it again.. take a look... 
 $datacount2 = mysql_num_rows($result );  
        if($datacount2 < 1)
        {

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`mysqli_stmt::affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) to find out if rows were affected. If not, you can print out your error message